# How to create multiple plots on the same graph in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

How I can plot the following graph in Matlab, and how to name av_d, av_c, ...

[image]

Thank you so much!

Comment: You need to provide example data, code you've tried, a specific problem... See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to improve the necessary information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started:

```
% Example data
x = 0:0.01:2*pi;
z = sin(x);
y = ones(size(x));
% Three identical lines plotted in x-z for different y
line([x;x;x;x]',[0*y;y;2*y;3*y]',[z;z;z;z]')
% Rename the yticks
set(gca,'YTickLabel',{'L1','L2','L3','L4'})
grid on
% Change the viewing angle
view(45,45)
```

Output: [image: Example MATLAB image using lines]